# Mdi parent form with other mdi parent form as a child

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to create two mdi parent forms one containing another. Is it possible to so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, Windows does not support nested MDI forms.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;74041

Comment: well that's too bad. Do you think devexpress components might have such ability?

Comment: @gun-armod - I'm not sure to be honest - I have not used their controls. They may provide some sort of functionality but I doubt it will be exactly what you require.